# PostgreSQL: how do I list all triggers that use a specific field?

Tags: postgresql, trigger

for example i have a student table with (studentid)
i want to get a list of triggers that use this field...

for example if in table X there is a trigger that uses studentid i want it to be shown in the query result.

Answer (score 3):

You can do that by querying pg_proc and pg_trigger,

```
SELECT t.tgname FROM pg_trigger t, pg_proc p 
WHERE t.tgfoid=p.oid AND p.prosrc like '%studentid%';
```

Comment: mmm the name of the column is studentid is used in other places... for example in another table i have studentidfor. this will make querry not working. the solution needs to be based on column unique identifier. also studentid can be a field in another table regardless of this one.

Comment: So you can't do this, triggers called functions, functions are based on source code, there is no hard link based on ooid attribute for sample.

Comment: but this is very problematic... if for example i have a column named "id" and i use this method i will get lots of results most of them are irrelevant.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to filter on the tablle name if you have too many triggers just add a filter on relname from pg_class

```
SELECT tgrelid::regclass,t.tgname FROM pg_trigger t, pg_proc p, pg_class c 
WHERE c.oid = t.tgrelid AND t.tgfoid=p.oid 
AND c.relkind = 'r'
AND p.prosrc LIKE '%studentid%' AND c.relname = 'X';
```